# Sub-space problem in complex space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, complex-numbers

A problem in my professor's guide is driving me nuts, I don't even know where to start, this is the problem:

*Is $ \{(z,u) \in \mathbb{C}^2 / z - \overline{z} + u = 0\} $ a sub-space of $ (\mathbb{C}^2,+,\mathbb{R},.)? $ If it is, find its base and dimension.*

I have solved similar problems to this one, the only difference is that the other ones didn't have complex numbers, also, what does $\overline{z}$ means in this problem?

**Edit:** I'm not asking you to solve the problem, just point me out in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that every complex number can be written in the form $z=a+bi$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Then with $z$ as above, $\overline{z}$ is defined to be $\overline{z}=a-bi$.

Thus, $z-\overline{z}+u=0$ means that $a+bi-(a-bi)+u=2bi+u=0$, and thus $u=-2bi$.  So the elements of the set you are looking at are of the form $(a+bi,-2bi)$.

To try and demystify the use of complex variables, another way you can think of the complex number $a+bi$ is as the ordered pair $(a,b)$.  In this case, the pair of complex numbers $((a,b),(c,d))$ can just be identified as the ordered quadruple $(a,b,c,d)$.  Thus, the set of points you're looking at are the quadruples $(a,b,0,-2b)$, where addition and scalar multiplication are defined component-wise.

Comment: That's the kind of help I needed!

Comment: Glad I could help, let me know if you get stuck on anything

Comment: Okay after some work I came the the conclution that the given set is a sub-space of the given space (it seems to satisfy the definition of a sub-space). And the basis of the set is $ a(1,0) + b(i, -2i) $ Am I right? Should I post the solution?

Comment: Yep, that would be (one of) the basis, though technically the basis is a set (in this case $\{(1,0),(i,-2i)\}$). If you want to post a new question verifying your solution though, go right ahead.